# access functions outside the class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

My class structure is something like this:

```
var jpTWUI = function(id, connection){
    this.id = id;
    this.muteButton = "#mute";
    this.hangupButton = "#hang";
    this.transferButton = "#trans";
    this.parentElement = jQuery('#timerCon');
    this.connection = connection;

    this.interval = "";

    this.createElements();
    this.addEvents(); 
};

jpTWUI.prototype = { 
    createElements: function(){ ... }, 
    addEvents: function(){...}, 
    startTimer: function(){...}
}
```

Now I have created an object and called the class something like this

```
var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', connection);
callHandler.startTimer();
```

But the problem is that the method `startTimer` has the `setInterval` function which display the duration in minutes and seconds.

I want to implement one more method like `stopTimer` which stop that `startTimer`'s interval, I know I have to user `window.clearInterval`. but when I implemented the function `stopTimer` in the same class then I don't know how do I access that method with the class like:

```
var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', device);
callHandler.stopTimer();
```

Hope you guys understand what I want to achieve, this is first time I have used the class in javascript..

Please guide me is this approach is correct?? 
or how do i make it correct..

Comment: you should get it's id in a variable while creating the timer, & pass it to clear function

Comment: @AshokRaj i had into the variable `this.interval = setInterval(function(){..}, 1000)` but i don't know how do i access this.interval into the stopTimer()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code. save return value of setInterval in setIntervalConst and use it clearInterval. 
You should use same instance of  jpTWUI while calling startTimer and stopTimer.

```
var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', connection);
callHandler.startTimer();

///var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', device); // remove this line if you want access same instance of jpTWUI.
callHandler.stopTimer();
```

.

```
jpTWUI.prototype = { 
    createElements: function(){ ... }, 
    addEvents: function(){...}, 
    setIntervalConst: 0,
    startTimer: function(){ this.setIntervalConst = setInterval(....) ....},
    stoptTimer: function(){ clearInterval(this.setIntervalConst ); ....}
}
```

Comment: can i use something like this??  `var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', device);
callHandler.startTimer();` and `var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', device);
callHandler.stopTimer();`

Comment: Yes you can. are you recreating jpTWUI object? you should intialize callHandler  only once.

Comment: can i do something like this `var callHandler = new jpTWUI('timerCon', device);` and call the methods separately like in a condition i want to call `callHandler.startTimer();` and in second condition i want to call `callHandler.stopTimer();` is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

get the id when creating and clear it.

```
this.interval = setInterval(function(){..}, 1000)
clearInterval(this.interval );
```

does this help your prob?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns an identifier that you can pass to `clearInterval` to stop a timer, so you could do something like this:

```
jpTWUI.prototype = { 
    …
    startTimer: function(){
        this.timer = setInterval(function(){
            console.log("interval")
        },2000) // every 2 seconds
    },
    stopTimer: function(){
        if(this.timer){
            clearInterval(this.timer);
        }
    }
}
```